# Azure API python SDK error "PrivateIPAddressIsBeingCleanedUp"

Tags: python, azure

Im trying to configure a network interface in Azure with an IP address and I'm seeing this error code as response:

```
Code: PrivateIPAddressIsBeingCleanedUp
Message: IP configuration deployment/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/0772E133C192_EXT_NIC_AEE/ipConfigurations/0772E133C192_EXT_NIC_AEE-172.26.226.48 is using the private IP address 172.26.226.48 which is being cleaned up and was allocated to resource deployment/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/0772E133C192_EXT_NIC_AEE
```

When I do a GET API on the interface there are no IP addresses assigned to it, but the PUT API throws this error code. Does anyone have any idea what is the reason here?

Answer (score 0):

> Code: PrivateIPAddressIsBeingCleanedUp Message: IP configuration
> deployment/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/0772E133C192_EXT_NIC_AEE/ipConfigurations/0772E133C192_EXT_NIC_AEE-172.26.226.48
> is using the private IP address 172.26.226.48 which is being cleaned
> up and was allocated to resource
> deployment/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/0772E133C192_EXT_NIC_AEE

This error code occurs when the IP address you’re trying to assign the Network Interface was already used by another resource in Azure Portal, or the resource using the IP address example- vm or vnet is deleted, After the resource is deleted the IP address would still show In use for some time but it will be available for resuse after the clean up process is completed or if the process of deleting NIC, Vnet or Vm using the same IP is in deleting state.

I created one VM > NIC and attached a Private IP to the VM’s NIC like below:-

[image]

Now, I deleted the above NIC and tried assigning the same IP to another VM’s NIC with the below python code:-

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient

from azure.mgmt.network.models import NetworkInterfaceIPConfiguration

  

# Set the subscription ID, resource group name, and network interface name

subscription_id = 'subscription-id'

resource_group_name = 'resource-group-name'

interface_name = 'NIC-name'

  

# Set the private IP address you want to assign

private_ip_address = '10.0.0.4'

  

# Create a NetworkManagementClient instance

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

  

# Get the network interface

interface = network_client.network_interfaces.get(resource_group_name, interface_name)

  

# Create a new IP configuration with the private IP address

ip_configuration = NetworkInterfaceIPConfiguration(

name='ipconfig2',

subnet=interface.ip_configurations[0].subnet,

private_ip_address=private_ip_address

)

  

# Add the new IP configuration to the network interface

interface.ip_configurations.append(ip_configuration)

  

# Update the network interface with the new IP configuration

network_client.network_interfaces.begin_create_or_update(resource_group_name, interface_name, interface)
```

***I waited for the previous VM’s NIC to get deleted completely and then ran the above script :-***

[image]

[image]

Ran the above code to assign the same 10.0.0.4 Private IP to another VM’s NIC and it got assigned successfully like below:-

Output:-

[image]

Portal:-

[image]

Reference:-
[Cannot use private IP address as it is either allocated to a resource or being cleaned up. · Issue #835 · Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/835)